# opencv: WarpPerspective irregular contour transformation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to apply perspective transformation to an image, but at the results, borders are irregular.

I need to replace objects in one image from others. Is necesarry apply some perspective transformation in order to adecuate the replacement. All is ok except for the irregular borders in the image transformed.

I tried different interpolation methods, different image qualities... but the problem is alwais the same.

There is an example:  https://ibb.co/tzQGBhx

I wrote some code to show you my problem.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

logo=cv2.imread('test3.jpg')

dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [logo.shape[1] - 1, 0],
    [logo.shape[1] - 1, logo.shape[0] - 1],
    [0, logo.shape[0] - 1]], dtype = "float32")


rect=np.float32([[260, 200], [520, 180], [530, 320], [260, 340]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(dst, rect)          
warp = cv2.warpPerspective(logo, M, (logo.shape[1]*2, logo.shape[0]*2),cv2.INTER_LINEAR  ,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT )
cv2.imshow('im',warp)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Care to show us examples ?

Comment: Of course.https://ibb.co/tzQGBhx

Comment: The problem is much clearer now. What you want is antialiased outlines. If the background is black, extend the source image with a black margin one or two pixels wide and transform the extended image.

Comment: If the background is another image, the situation is a little more complicated. A possible method is to apply the reverse transform to the background image and draw it inside the margin of the extended image (you can transform the whole image on the extended area, then paint the foreground image over). Finally, transform the extended image.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried but the problem persist.

Comment: Show your new code, this must work.